# Long tour in winter

Tags: touring, winter

I'm thinking of doing a longish (1-2 months) tour starting around November.
I will start in Germany, and the destination is not important to me.

I have done one day tours in the German winter, and I can't say I enjoyed myself too much. Riding under pouring rain and in freezing temperatures is unsafe and not so fun.

Is there a route I can take to (mostly) avoid this kind of weather? Does anyone here have experience with a similar tour?

I was thinking of something along these lines:

[image: map]

Comment: I'm not sure you'll get much of a response to this question on this site since it's just a subjective topic, not something you can give a clear Correct/ Incorrect answer to. If you find you don't get a satisfactory response, I would recommend you try asking the same question on the forums on http://www.crazyguyonabike.com, and also explore journals from other people who have toured in the same area.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on travel.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

I live in Hungary and riding until the middle of December is usually not a problem. I would go as fast and as far south as possible and maybe I would finish my ride in Athens. It's a popular destination. As you're a beginner for safety reasons you shouldn't go to Turkey or further.
The other option would be to ride to Gibraltar. I've been there in January and I was riding in summer clothes. 
But probably you should go on your first big tour in the summer, it's much more enjoyable to ride in nice weather.
And the last thing is: YOU SHOULD NOT GO ON A TOUR WITHOUT A DESTINATION! Cycle touring is mainly about the journey and not only about the destination. However riding without one can really hurt your mood. You have to have a goal because, like in other aspects of life, it won't work without one.